# unsafe method trouble rewriting it without /unsafe

Tags: c#

I have some code that was written in unsafe code.
can somebody help me convert it to normal managed code? I don't know how to do it because i don't understand what it's actually doing. Please educate me on what is happening in here.

```
public byte[] GetRowData(int row)
{
    var buffer = new byte[Cols * 6];

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* lpData = buffer, lpTile = &Data[row * Cols * 6])
        {
            var lpD = lpData;
            var lpT = lpTile;

            for (var i = 0; i < Cols; i++, lpD += 6, lpT += 6)
            {
                lpD[0] = lpT[1];
                lpD[1] = lpT[0];

                lpD[2] = lpT[3];
                lpD[3] = lpT[2];

                lpD[4] = lpT[5];
                lpD[5] = lpT[4];
            }
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: I think I have mostly parsed what the function does. The only missing elements are the value of Cols and what is in the Collection Data. Because for needles complexity, he of coruse got 2/3 the input from a global source rather then a function argument :)

Answer (score 1):

Pointers. They are arguably the single most *fundamental* tool of coding. They are also arguably the single most *dangerous* tool of coding. I have worked with them, and they are like "juggling live handgrenades"

The .NET developers tried their best so you would not have to handle them. And indeed could not handle them by default. If you *do* need to handle them, you have to dip into unsafe code. unsafe is there to allow the use of that byte pointer `byte*`.

`fixed` is a hint for the GarbageCollector: "Do not move this from the memory location as part of your work. You would mess up my code."

Edit:

There is so much wrong and odd with the code, it needed a comment to even figure out *what it is doing*. So your confusion si expected I will try to explain it with comments:

```
/*The function signature. row is the only data he does not get from a global source. Because of course he get's half the input from global sources, otherwise it would not be hard enough to read!
It seems to do a combined copy and swap operation. And in batches of 6 elements, for some reason*/
public byte[] GetRowData(int row)
{
    //He creates a managed array. It's size is a external value called "Cols" times 6. I hope that at least Cols is a constant, but I doubt it.
    //This is also the output variable. Later known as lpData and lpD.
    var buffer = new byte[Cols * 6];

    //He enters unsafe code, to do his pointer shenanigans.
    unsafe
    {
        //he gets a pointer to the start of the buffer (lpData)
        //he gets a pointer to whatever is in "row * Cols * 6" of the global Data Collection. So this is the part where he actually retrieves the INPUT, based on the argument he gave this function.
        //If Data[row * Cols * 6] is smaler then Cols * 6/buffer.lenght, he already fucked up.
        //He also tells the GC to not optimize those around the memory space. He needs nobody else doing stuff in that area.
        fixed (byte* lpData = buffer, lpTile = &Data[row * Cols * 6])
        {
            //Indexing in arrays with pointers is done with some Pointer Arythmetic: Start Pointer + Index times type width - that is the memory adress you write at.
            //This is defintely the part where most people messed up with pointers. Also the only way to do it. And why the .NET Array will do this for you only after sanity checks on the index.
            //He makes local copies of the pointers, becaus he will do some of the Arithmethic himself - but not all of it
            var lpD = lpData;
            var lpT = lpTile;

            //A for loop. i is jsut your normal running variable to control how many itterations there will be.
            //each itteration he will also count lpD and lpT up by 6, to get the next "batch" of elements.
            for (var i = 0; i < Cols; i++, lpD += 6, lpT += 6)
            {
                //He processes the batch of 6 elements. He copies 6 element from input to output, while also swapping the odd and even elements.
                //Mathwise those indexers work out to: Pointer of the array start + i*6 + stated index * element width
                lpD[0] = lpT[1];
                lpD[1] = lpT[0];

                lpD[2] = lpT[3];
                lpD[3] = lpT[2];

                lpD[4] = lpT[5];
                lpD[5] = lpT[4];
            }
        }
    }

    //We are back out of unsafe code, the pointers have all gone out of scope and he returns whatever he created there in input, from whatever was in Data[row * Cols * 6]
    return buffer;
}
```

To figure out what this is supposed to do, I would need to know what the elements of `Data` look like.

Comment: Look more carefully--there's no swapping going on.  It's copying but with some values transposed.  lpD and lpT are local copies **of pointers**, not local copies of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided is copying data from the memory address `lpTile` to `lpData`, that's pretty much it.

To *convert* it to code which doesn't use `unsafe` and `fixed` would be something like this, **but** only if `Data` is a byte array, else you will need to use `unsafe` to fix the object at the `Data` array's start index sins, say that the array is of type `int`, in the provided unsafe code the data which is being copied are **bytes** so, if you will want to do it to a `int`, you will either have to use `unsafe` or do shift right (`>>`) 0, 8, 16 & 24 and get the bytes that way for each int value which is retrieved from the `Data` array.

If the array is of a struct type which is more "complex" say something like the [SYSTEMTIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime) struct, while it will be possible to get bytes for each field in the struct, it will more than likely give you a headache writing it all out.

> This example will only work if Data is a byte array.

```
var buffer = new byte[Cols * 6];

int b_pos = 0;

int d_pos = (row * Cols * 6);

for (var i = 0; i < Cols; i++, b_pos += 6, d_pos += 6)
{
    buffer[b_pos + 0] = Data[d_pos + 1];

    buffer[b_pos + 1] = Data[d_pos + 0];

    buffer[b_pos + 2] = Data[d_pos + 3];

    buffer[b_pos + 3] = Data[d_pos + 2];

    buffer[b_pos + 4] = Data[d_pos + 5];

    buffer[b_pos + 5] = Data[d_pos + 4];
}

return buffer;
```

Note that using pointers and `unsafe` isn't bad, it's there for a reason so, if converting that code to something that isn't unsafe isn't a big issue, I would recommend keeping it that way rather than messing with it. Mind you that quite a bit of code in `mscorlib.dll` uses pointer, for example the `ToCharArray` function in the `String` class, while it may seam to be safe, actually its completely based on pointers and copying data from one memory address to another.

> **Update**

After looking at the code, I realized that it's `fixed byte*` so the `Data` array is of type byte.

Here are 2 examples one using `fixed` and another not, with what is happening in each:

`fixed` Example:

```
public unsafe byte[] GetRowData(int row)
{
    //The total length which will be used as buffer length, Data array start index multiple & for loop length
    int totalLength = (Cols * 6);

    //Allocates a byte array of size totalLength
    var buffer = new byte[totalLength];

    //Gets the memory address of the byte in Data at [row * totalLength]
    //which, when moved forwards, leads to the next byte in the Data array i.e. at [(row * totalLength) + 1], because data in a array is sequential.
    fixed (byte* dataptr = &Data[row * totalLength])
    {
        //Does a for loop with the end being totalLength and adding to "i" itself 6 instead of some external variables.
        for (var i = 0; i < totalLength; i += 6)
        {
            //moves data from the fixed address "dataptr" to the byte array "buffer"
            buffer[i] = dataptr[i + 1];

            buffer[i + 1] = dataptr[i];

            buffer[2] = dataptr[i + 3];

            buffer[3] = dataptr[i + 2];

            buffer[4] = dataptr[i + 5];

            buffer[5] = dataptr[i + 4];
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Example without `fixed`

```
public byte[] GetRowData(int row)
{
    //Same as in the above example, the total length.
    int totalLength = (Cols * 6);

    //Same allocation of the buffer size of totalLength
    var buffer = new byte[totalLength];

    //The index at which to start moving data from the Data array
    int dataStartIndex = (row * totalLength);

    //The same for loop as in the above example
    for (var i = 0; i < totalLength; i += 6)
    {
        //Moves data from the Data array at index [dataStartIndex + i + n] to the buffer array.
        buffer[i] = Data[dataStartIndex + i + 1];

        buffer[i + 1] = Data[dataStartIndex + i];

        buffer[2] = Data[dataStartIndex + i + 3];

        buffer[3] = Data[dataStartIndex + i + 2];

        buffer[4] = Data[dataStartIndex + i + 5];

        buffer[5] = Data[dataStartIndex + i + 4];
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Mind you, what I said before about the `Data` array, if it were not of type `byte` is true, if it were not one then you would need to use `fixed` or find a way to get bytes from each variable retrieved from the array but, sins `Data` is a byte array all of the 3 examples above will work.

Answer (score 0):

These are all array operations.  They are walking the pointer through the array so they can use fixed offsets in each case.

Obviously I haven't tested this but my inclination:

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < Cols; loop++)
{
    int Offset = loop * 6;
    lpD[Offset + 0] = lpT[Offset + 1];
    lpD[Offset + 1] = lpT[Offset + 0];
    lpD[Offset + 2] = lpT[Offset + 3];
    lpD[Offset + 3] = lpT[Offset + 2];
    lpD[Offset + 4] = lpT[Offset + 5];
    lpD[Offset + 5] = lpT[Offset + 4];
}
```

I can't convert the rest of this because we don't have the whole picture here.  I'm sure the remaining pointers can be replaced by offsets into the array along the lines of what I did here.

I strongly suspect this is some matrix code that was originally written in C and someone did a minimal-effort port to C#.